# Drag images using handle graphic

Tags: javascript, html

Using javascript and or html5, I'm trying to drag 4 connecting images in the browser, attached to a gripper/handle graphic, The four images will also have linkages attached to them.
So basically the handle will be draggable not necessary the images. Just want to be able to
move the images around a defined area on the screen.

Thanks,
Stonian

---

I was able to create 99% of what i am trying to achieve. The only problem i am having is to dynamically being able to change the word/Label to say "Residential" when the event of dragging a second filmstrip occurs. There are going to be 2 filmstrips. One for commercial and one for residential. Whichever one you drag the name needs to change. I can use some help getting the name change to work. I have tried but it's proving to be challenging. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
See the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="boilerplate.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Page2.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="demos.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">

 <script>
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ handle: "p" });
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ cursor: "crosshair" });
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ containment: "none" });
});



</script>   

</head>
<body>



<div id="primaryContainer" class="primaryContainer clearfix">
    <div id="box" class="clearfix">
    </div>
    <div id="box1" class="clearfix">
    </div>
    <p id="text">
    <span id="effect">Commercial</span><br />
    </p>

<div id="wood" class="clearfix">




    <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">

        <p class="ui-widget-header"><img id="image" src="img/film1_01.png" class="image" /></p>
        <img id="image1" src="img/film1_02.png" class="image" />
        <a href="RateCard.html" target="_blank" ><img id="image2" src="img/film1_03.png" class="image" />
        <a href="RateCard2.html" target="_blank" ><img id="image3" src="img/film1_04.png" class="image" />
        <img id="image4" src="img/film1_05.png" class="image" />
        <img id="image5" src="img/film1_06.png" class="image" />
        <img id="image6" src="img/film1_07.png" class="image" />
    </div></div>
    <p id="text1">
    <span id="textspan1">Drag a film strip and select the video you want to see.</span><br />
    </p>
</div>



</body>
```

Comment: What's the question? What's the problem? Where is your code?

Comment: please provide a proper question following a code example.

Comment: not quite sure what you need yet but your `draggable` initialisations, do you not need to include all the options in one initalisation? Otherwise you are initialising it three times. `$( "#draggable" ).draggable({ handle: "p", cursor: "crosshair", containment: "none" });`